# Ctrl-S doesn't work in rtorrent when accessed via screen. Can't start torrents

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen, rtorrent

I run `rtorrent` remotely on a seedbox. When I log in with a web interface I'm able to start torrents, and when torrent files get dropped into my watched folder that works too. However, when I try to start them by SSHing in to my seedbox and `-r` resuming the `screen` session that contains my instance of `rtorrent`, I can't seem to use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> keyboard shortcut to start torrents. I can stop and delete them with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> shortcut, and as far as I can tell all the other keyboard shortcuts work.

I've tried this from the Terminal app in OSX and from Cygwin on Windows.

Thanks for your insight!

Comment: I should add that in both of these cases, if I run rTorrent locally I don't have this issue. Only when running it remotely via SSH and screen. I'm not sure whether the issue is with screen or ssh, or something else.

Comment: Have you tried using PuTTY on windows ?

Comment: I have not and won't be back at my Windows machine until some time tomorrow to try it. That said, I think it's something on the remote end, not on my end. I've tried one more terminal application in the mean time: iSSH on an iPad. Same issue.

Comment: What exactly happens when you press C-S? My fist thought is that C-S sends XOFF to your terminal.

Comment: It seems as if nothing at all happens when I press Ctrl-s. Other keyboard shortcuts work, just not this one.

Comment: Also, when you run rTorrent locally, do you run it in a screen ? or in a plain terminal ? I've also found different terminals / PuTTY / other windows terminals handles CTRL- shortcuts differently at times.

Answer (score 4):

I eventually found the answer for myself [on this page.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/RTorrent#Redundant_mapping)

The machine I was running `rtorrent` on had <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> mapped to stop and start screen output. Unmapping these got things working again.

Comment: `screen`'s flow toggle `C-a C-f` might help with these shortcuts. In `-flow` mode they may be passed on to the program.

Comment: Great. Now what's `-flow` mode? And what is `C-a C-f`?

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to keep the use of those keyboard commands outside rtorrent, here's an alias to only unset them when you run rtorrent:

```
alias rtorrent='stty stop undef ; stty start undef ; rtorrent'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are my aliases to start `rtorrent` in the background and display the client using `screen`:

```
alias rtorrent-start='stty stop undef ; stty start undef ; screen -d -m -S rtorrentd rtorrent'
alias rtorrent='screen -DR rtorrentd'
```

I had a little trouble figuring out which alias should contain the `stty` commands. But this seems to be workable. I still get the notification in my terminal (`konsole`) when doing a Ctl-S or Ctl-Q but now the commands pass through to `rtorrent`.

I'd still like to get rid of the terminal notifications so please let me know if there's a better way.